# Featured questions button missing

Tags: feature-request, bounty

On the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) homepage, there's a featured questions tab where questions with bounties are displayed.  There's a [similar page](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) for DSP, but no tab on the homepage.  Is it a bug that the tab isn't displayed, or is this intentional since there are currently no questions with bounties?  As a new user, I find this confusing.

Edit: I'd like to request that the featured question button always be displayed to avoid confusion.  For a smaller site like this one, it's also a good way to advertise the bounty functionality to people who haven't experienced the very active bounty system on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a bug.  It just means that there are no questions with open bounties.

A week or so ago, it was there. That was because I had an open bounty on a question. The bounty is now closed, so there are no featured questions.